# In Django CMS, how can I prevent duplicate items in a queryset when I order them by .order_by('title_set__title')

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms, prefetch, changelist

Let's say I am viewing a changelist for a set of pages in a Django CMS project and I want to sort that by title. But for each title/language that is created and published, a duplicate tree item will be displayed. For any other kind of sorting that I have created, this does not happen and it works as it should. This will return one tree item for each language that has been published and I am pretty sure created as well. Even with the *.distinct()* it will return one tree item for each title/language that exists. Examples below.

This example produces duplicate or even 3, 4, 5 copies of the same tree item if there are that many language titles that exist, such as *('en', 'fr', 'de, and 'es' titles)*.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(PageAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    queryset = queryset.order_by('title_set__title').distinct()
```

Now in this example, if I order tree items by anything else, or *(-publication_date, publication_end_date, -publication_end_date)*. I will only get one result for pages that have multiple titles/languages that exist, just like it should.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(PageAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    queryset = queryset.order_by('publication_date').distinct()
```

My educated guess is that it has something to do with the *"title_set"*, which is being prefetched elsewhere, being a collection of many titles (1 for each language) versus it being a single title, the language that is selected in the change-list results.

In both of these methods;

> def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):

and

> def get_tree(self, request):

of

> Class BasePageAdmin(PlaceholderAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

This is where the prefetch is running. These all came standard with the package. I have modified some things as I am building a custom system around this, but this part is still mostly how the package came. So I'm guessing I just need a better understanding about how either *Django-CMS* works and/or how *prefetch_related()* can be used. My knowledge is not Master Jedi level yet.

```
pages = pages.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'title_set',
        to_attr  = 'filtered_translations',
        queryset = Title.objects.filter(language__in=get_language_list(site.pk))
    ),
)
```

I'm running these major components;

> Django==2.2.9

> django-cms==3.7.1

> python 3.7.8

> Windows 10

Comment: Not sure if that applies here, but could it have something to do with the fact that "each published page in the CMS exists in as two cms.Page instances: public and draft" (see the [docs](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/topics/publishing.html))?

Comment: Good thought but likely not the cause for this to happen. I've been trying to wrap my head around that though, so we are both thinking in the same direction at least. If I publish a page in French, German, Russian and Italian, I would get 5 copies, the fifth being the English one. And if each title.title has different text for each language, it will still display just the english for all 5 entries. I'm not even sure how django-cms sorts by tile.title in an admin changelist view. Perhaps I'm just not sorting properly per however django-cms is supposed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this and needs a solution, I found a solution or at least a good work around. If this is not the proper way to sort a list of Pages by its related Title.title in Django-CMS then I would love to learn the right way.

What I ended up doing was sorting/ordering my queryset the way that I wanted, by the title of the related Title of the Page. I then converted the queryset into a values_list of id's of Pages. I then removed any duplicates within that list and then taxed another query to the database to get a new queryset, retrieving only the id's in the values_list and preserves the order I had the values_list in. Since I am performing another query of the database to get a new set of Pages, this is where I don't think this is the proper way to do this, but it will definitely get the job done and you won't have duplicates. If someone has a better way please share.

```
from django.db.models import Case, When
```

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super(PageAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

    pk_list = queryset.order_by('title_set__title').values_list('id', flat=True)

    pk_list_cleaned = []
    [pk_list_cleaned.append(x) for x in pk_list if x not in pk_list_cleaned]

    preserved_order = Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(pk_list_cleaned)])
    queryset = Page.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list_cleaned).order_by(preserved_order)
```